# undefined field text Solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying to do a sample program to search using solrj.
My code is below
Basically i am trying to search for a word which contains every where in book_name field.
When search for more than one word i am getting the Exception

```
HttpSolrClient solr=new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/Books");
          System.out.println("here we go");
          SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
          query.setQuery("book_name:indian poems");
          QueryResponse response=solr.query(query);
          System.out.println(response.toString());
```

but its showing an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/Books: undefined field text.
```

But if i search it for one word its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Probably `text` is your default search field.

...depending on your search handler configuration: This means for your case probably: if your search query is `book_name:indian poems`, solr searches for the word `indian` in the field `book_name` and searches for `poems` in the default search field - depending on your `solr.xml` configuration.

So if you like to search for both words in that field, the following should work:

```
query.setQuery("book_name:indian book_name:poems");
```

An other option is, to set the default search field to `book_name`, for example by changeing the `solr.xml` or defining the `qf` parameter for each query.

I'm not familiar with `solrj`, but something like this could work:

```
query.set("qf", "book_name");
```

Comment: query.setQuery("book_name:indian book_name:poems");
It won't give me book names which contains both the words in the book_name field, it gives me the result either any word out of whole given words

Comment: that depends on your search handler configruation and your default operater, which seamst to be `OR`. You can cahnge this to `AND` or change your query like this: 

`query.setQuery("book_name:indian book_name:poems");`
 or if you like to search an phrase: `query.setQuery('book_name:"indian poems"');`

Comment: You can also use brackets to direct several words to one field, like `query.setQuery("book_name:(indian poems)");`. This is less strict than a phrase.